# Azure Pipelines: The session ... has exceeded the maximum state size threshold of 235520 bytes

Tags: azure-pipelines

My Azure Pipelines build, running tests on a self-provided agent fails with the following error message:

```
The session 967fec09-b99b-4f33-adc3-1a0122a12fe7.runondefaultagentpool.__default has exceeded the maximum state size threshold of 235520 bytes.
```

This is the link to the build run:

https://dev.azure.com/rmetzger/Flink/_build/results?buildId=187&view=logs&j=96e03a1a-0ac4-5903-83b1-91e6a9dce517

I don't understand what the state size threshold is, whether I can increase it, or if there's a way for me to resolve this issue?

I would ignore this error, if this would not have caused this entire machine to stop accepting new jobs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can refer to this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c36956ff-a7e3-41ad-9aa3-134bfd6e52f7/state-size-error?forum=tfsbuild) with the similar issue.

Comment: That's the only search result I got when searching for the error. But I could not get anything helpful out of that discussion, that's why I posted here.

Comment: @HughLin That link is dead now unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

The size doesn't seem to be the problem, only the symptom. 
Your build step "Maven" have been running for almost 31 days before stopping.
Find out why it's taking so long and you'll find your problem.
[image: build screenshot]

Comment: I noticed this and will introduce a timeout for the maven build.